# o.addClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the ID of the clicked anchor and add a class to the element with same ID.

```
$galleryItem.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $galleryProjectContent = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log($galleryProjectContent);

    $galleryProject.addClass('d-block slideInUp animated');
    $body.css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $galleryProjectContent.addClass('d-block');
});
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: o.addClass is not a function.

Comment: *"I get Uncaught TypeError: o.addClass is not a function."* That suggests you're trying to debug minified code (`o` instead of `$galleryProjectContent`). It's best to debug non-minified code. (And then of course, *test* minified code, to avoid errors introduced by minification. But first, debug the un-minified code.)

Comment: Which line has the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
var $galleryProjectContent = $(this).attr("id");
```

`$galleryProjectContent` is a **string**, not a jQuery object or a DOM element.

You've said:

> I want to get the ID of the clicked anchor and add a class to the element with same ID.

There's no reason to get the ID and then look up the element with the ID, you already *have* the element: `this`. It has to be the element you're looking for (since `id` values **must** be unique on the page). To get a jQuery wrapper for it, just use `$(this)`. So simply:

```
var $galleryProjectContent = $(this);
```

---

**If** you needed to get an element by an ID that you have as a string, you could do it like this:

```
var $x = $("#" + theId);
// or
var $x = $(document.getElementById(theId));
```

But again, there's no reason to do that here.

Comment: @NikaPichkhaia - Glad that helped! But I missed a key thing in the question. Please see the updated answer. The old answer *worked*, but there's no reason to do it that way. :-)